# Does non-relativistic length contraction affect the field lines of a particle in a dielectric

Tags: special-relativity, dielectric

Lets say you have a dielectric where the speed of light inside of it is extremely low. Lets then shoot a charged particle into the dielectric so that it is going at 50% the speed of light inside the dielectric. Will its field lines contract in the direction of motion? The particle won't be affected by relativistic length contraction since its speed is extremely low compared to the actual speed of light. Its not clear to me whether or not the field lines will contract though.

Comment: Is the particle velocity faster or slower than the speed of light in the dielectric? If the former you'll get Cherenkov radiation.

Comment: Slower. It is going half as fast as light would through the dielectric.

Comment: Are you familiar with solutions to Maxwell's equations with a moving source?

Comment: Somewhat I suppose. A refresher wouldn't hurt.